# What is a geometric interpretation of $0x+0y=0$

Tags: analytic-geometry, geometric-construction

What is a geometric interpretation of $$0x+0y=0.$$ I would think of this as a plane... Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it is the classic Cartesian plane, or $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$0x+0y=0$ is satisfied for every point $(x,y)$, this equation therefore describes the entire plane $\mathbb R^2$ or whatever space you are working with.